# Assigning a variable rather than checking for truth value with ->

Tags: if-statement, prolog, conditional-statements, variable-assignment, unification

I am attempting to assign a variable with an empty list like this:

```
stuff(_) :- (not(is_list(X)) -> X is []), ...
```

or

```
stuff(_) :- (not(is_list(X)) -> X = []), ...
```

What I want is for `X` to meet the condition that `X` is not a list in order to assign `X` with an empty list. It can't be like:

```
 not(is_list(X)), X = []
```

Because *"`X` is not list"* condition must be met. But when I try the above code, all it does is try to check the truth value of `X = []` or `X is []` instead of assigning `X` with the empty list.

I don't necessary have to use `->`. It can be anything. As long as `X` is assigned `[]` if `X` is not already a list. As the consequent of `stuff(_)` relation.

Comment: It looks as if you wanted to use Prolog like an imperative language, because variable assignment like you expect does not exist (variables can become instantiated but they never change their value. Have a look at the query `X=1, X=2.` to see this in effect).  Also, you propose a rule "If X is not a list, then X is the empty list." which does not make sense from a logical point of view. Perhaps you could give the context of the problem you would like to solve?

Comment: `\+ is_list(X).` is *always* true, with an uninstantiated ("fresh") logical variable `X`. so `(not(is_list(X)) -> X = [])` is *always* the same as `X=[]`, when `X` is fresh (like you show). So here it indeed comes down to what the meaning of the word "is" is, when you say "condition that `X` is not a list". `X` per se is a fresh logvar, of course it's not a list *right now*, by definition. But if you mean something else by that "is", well, do clarify what it *is*. :)

Comment: as for "assignment", Prolog doesn't have it. It has [tag:unification] instead.

Comment: You should check the Prolog documentation. `X is []` is attempting to use an *arithmetic expression assignment* operator (`is`) as some kind of general assignment, which will give you an error since `[]` is not an evaluable arithmetic expression. Also, note that `is_list([])` is true, So it's not clear what you're really trying to do here, since the condition, `not(is_list(X)), X = []` is telling Prolog that you want `X` not to be a list, but you want `X` to be unifiable with `[]`, which is a logical contradiction. If `X` is already pre-instantiated (bound), then you cannot re-bind it.

Comment: There's only one way you can bind `X` to `[]`: if `X` is previously *unbound*. Using your incorrect terminology, you cannot *reassign* `X` if it has already been *assigned*. That's not how Prolog treats variables in a predicate.

Comment: In case it isn't clear from the other comments, you are experiencing deep confusion about how to go about using Prolog to solve a problem. I would strongly recommend you stop working on whatever problem motivated this, and start with a Prolog tutorial or book _from page one_. Prolog _really does not work like other languages_ and you will only get yourself more confused if you try to press on.

Comment: I solved it. I used an auxiliary relation i.e. func_helper([]) and used (not(is_list(X)) -> func_helper(X)), but it wasn't much use, because I redesigned the whole thing, because I kept getting too many bugs with that design, and it all worked out.